# Can NSDateformatter be used for reading swedish months

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting, nslocale

I am trying to parse a list of dates. The dates look like this: "01MAY16, 01JUN16, 01AUG16" and so on. Up until now the dates have all been in english and I have successfully used the NSDateFormatter like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMMyy"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US")

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01MAY16")
```

I have now stumbled upon an issue. The dates I parse have a tendency to be displayed with swedish locale like this: "01MAJ16, 01JUN16, 01OKT16".
I was hoping this could be parsed by setting the locale in the dateformatter to swedish like this:

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMMyy"
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "sv_SE")

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01MAJ16")
```

This works fine when the date is 'MAJ', but only because that month is a 3-letter month. If I try the following the date returned is nil:

```
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01JUN16")
```

It returns nil because the format it is looking for is apparently 'juni'. So the format MMM does not imply 3-letters.

So to my question. What is the easiest way to solve this? Is there a trick I can use or do I have to create my own formatter?

**EDIT**

I learned a lot of new things from you, thank you.
Setting the shortMonthSymbols manually is a good solution, but in my case I would have to do that for both norwegian, swedish and danish locale. I came up with a solution that overrides the dateFromString() method of the NSDateFormatter. Please tell me if I have done something very stupid.
This formatter is used when I know that all the dates I parse (any locale) always uses 3-letter month:

```
class CustomDateFormatter : NSDateFormatter {

override func dateFromString(string: String) -> NSDate? {

    guard let date = super.dateFromString(string) else {

        //I only override the dateFormatter if no date is found and the dateFormat is set to exactly 3 M's (i.e ddMMMyy)
        let charactersInDateFormat = self.dateFormat.characters

        let mChars = charactersInDateFormat.filter { $0 == "M" }

        guard mChars.count == 3 else {

            return nil
        }

        var modifiedDateString = string.lowercaseString

        for monthLocale in self.shortMonthSymbols {

            let index = monthLocale.startIndex.advancedBy(3)

            let threeLetterMonthString = monthLocale.substringToIndex(index).lowercaseString

            if modifiedDateString.containsString(threeLetterMonthString) {

                modifiedDateString = modifiedDateString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(threeLetterMonthString, withString: monthLocale)

                break
            }
        }

        return super.dateFromString(modifiedDateString)
    }

    return date
}

}
```

Comment: All date formats are documented in http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns. "MMM" stands for the "abbreviated month", but that is not necessarily three letters (as in "Sept").

Comment: Yes, I know that the format MMM does not imply 3-letters. So what can I use to define that it should be 3 letters?

Comment: I cannot see such a format in the Unicode documentation, so I am afraid that you have to create your own parser.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I'll go ahead and do my own formatting:)

Comment: @fisher You don't have to necessarily create a new formatter/parser, you can also set month names explicitly on `NSDateFormatter`, ignoring locale settings completely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers are right. This is not a standard unicode format so changing locale won't help you. However, you can set month names explicitly!

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "ddMMMyy"
dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "maj", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "okt", "nov", "dec"];

let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("01JUN16")
print(date)
```

Comment: Excellent, I did not know that.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that `shortMonthSymbols` was writeable.

Answer (score 2):

You're out of luck with `NSDateFormatter`. Try this and you'll see:

```
print("Short month symbols: \(dateFormatter.shortMonthSymbols)")
```

This prints `["jan.", "feb.", "mars", "apr.", "maj", "juni", "juli", "aug.", "sep.", "okt.", "nov.", "dec."]`

I don't know what's common in Sweden, but as far as `NSDateFormatter` is concerned, "JUN" is not a valid short date name for Swedish formats. Using `shortStandaloneMonthSymbols` gives nearly the same result ("Juni" rather than "Jun", at least), so replacing `MMM` with `LLL` isn't going to help either (though in some languages it does).